# I love you guys/gals - Appreciation Thread

Tags: discussion

Before you downvote, I've examined the Help section thoroughly and it says that meta is for the following:

- Chemistry Stack Exchange users to communicate with each other about Chemistry Stack Exchange

I'm allowed to communicate with you about Chem:SE and you are undoubtedly apart of that.

---

Lets face it.  Chem:SE has had its fair share of moments from its infamous drama to its shining moments.  We graduated.  We've made it.  Its been quite a journey (if I may say so without sounding overdramatic) but it certainly has been quite... the... journey... .

I'm certain I'll be missing some people who well deserve to be mentioned here but let us give credit to some of the following people who have been here from nearly the beginnings.

**Jonsca** - Our fearless leader who has done more for this community than probably gets credit for.  You set a great example for what a moderator should be.  And you have been instrumental in getting us to where we are today as a community.

**ManishEarth** - You've been around for a very long time as well sacrificing a lot of your time for this site.

The chemistry giants who seem to be more machine than man... **ron**, **Klaus Warzecha**, **Ben Norris**, **F'x**, **Philip**, **Greg E.** - I stand in awe to your diverse knowledge of chemistry and how you are seemingly able to offer such incredible knowledge to a wide array of questions.  I just cannot even begin to comprehend how you manage to know so much about Chemistry.

**Dissenter** - You always seem to ask really good questions... and a LOT of them.  I've always enjoyed your posts on Chem:SE as well as your discussions in chat.  I hope you come visit us again someday.  You brought a lot of insight to our community.

**tschoppi** - Your enthusiasm really is quite a lesson we can all take from you.  The chatroom always benefits from you chiming in every once in a while.

**Geoff Hutchison** - Avogadro2??? Maybe?! SOON!?!  #GetHyped2016

And finally...

**Martin** - The German who lives in Japan who seriously contributes so much to this community.  There is hardly a question you'll find he hasn't edited, or a day that goes by that he hasn't checked into chat.  Martin has devoted so much of his time to this community its unbelievable.  Always welcoming... always level headed... Martin is a role-model for most of us.

Thanks guys. Thank you so much for everything you've brought to the table.  I might be the only one gushing right now but I'm sure I speak for others when I say wholeheartedly...

$$\mathrm{Thank~you}$$

Leave your appreciation below.  Lets keep this post alive for at least a little while before we close it as being off-topic (please).  :)

Comment: No, this is fine to have here.  We'll bend the rules a little bit. :)  Thank you, too, for your kind wishes and your steady participation! I definitely shouldn't be the headliner!

Comment: Nice one! Well deserved kudos to all there!  I hope to one day be able to contribute sufficiently to be considered in such a great way.

Comment: I took the opportunity in the site graduation thread to express my gratitude, too! It's great to be around friendly, interesting and dedicated folk like you guys. Truly an honour to be here.

Comment: Posts like this always make me stop and reflect on the nice folks I've met here and the fun I've had here.  Tonight I'll raise a glass to all the people I've met on the Chem SE road!

Comment: @ron We will have to raise a round for you and everyone else as well.  I'm glad to have everyone around, but especially the core folks!!

Comment: @jonsca and a great thing is, as time progresses, that core will grow as more professionals and enthusiasts not only join the ranks, but work, enjoyably, to make this place great!

Comment: I'm glad I read this meta post. The community that has developed here is awesome and I am happy to be a part of it.

Comment: @BenNorris You have hung with us from the start, so we are especially grateful for that.

Comment: You're welcome! :D And thanks to the awesome community for making this place the wonderful place it is! We keep this place clean, it's you folks who make it sparkle! :)

Comment: *I'm certain I'll be missing some people who well deserve to be mentioned....* You missed me, of course. :D ... Ahh, I also thought of writing a post like this, but I <strike>feared the downvotes</strike ;)> didn't have the time because of the exam season. Bottom line is, as @santiago says, I hope I'll be contributing well enough to be in that list... In a hopefully **far** future. :)

Comment: It's been wonderful seeing the community that's developed on this site, I'm glad you're taking a moment to appreciate it. You have much to be proud of.

Comment: I have said "sorry" to most of the above people for my stupid mistakes. I have also said "Thanks" for correcting stupid mistake :) Really this are people who have worked really well to make Chem. S.E. what it is today. And yes you have missed one person **"LordStryker"**