# Where's ron and Klaus Warzecha for the election?

Tags: discussion

Since for some reason I cannot get into chat, I decided to just ask the question here. I really wanted ron and Klaus to participate in the elections.

They've contributed the most to this website alongside jonsca, ManishEarth.

Why didn't they? Do you guys know?

---

**EDIT:** Thank you all for making this such a great community. Just wanted to see where the Chemistry dudes were at!

Comment: Also, why don't they ever pop into chat more often? :(

Comment: But if they nominated, we'd lose at least some of the valuable content they generously contribute.

Comment: BTW, why can't you reach chat?

Comment: Its weird, a connection failed screen shows up every time.

Comment: That *is* weird. If you're sure it's not an internet/computer/browser problem, you might post a `bug` in meta.SE.

Answer (score 29):

Think about amateur astronomers; half of them just love to build telescopes, the other half just love to look through them - it takes both kinds to make it work. I'm just happy to be a part of what we all share here at Chem SE.  @LordStryker said it best, [I love you guys/gals](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2759/i-love-you-guys-gals-appreciation-thread).

Comment: Here, here. :-)

Answer (score 20):

I seriously considered to nominate myself and admittedly, vanity did play a role in these thoughts ;) Eventually, I decided against it, and since you kindly asked, this is why:

Having answered a question or two during my time here, I do seem to have some professional experience in different fields of chemistry, like to solve problems using Python and I don't mind to answer questions on "problematic" topics. In adition, I despise rude behaviour, do not argue with crackpots and do not believe in 3rd and 4th chances for pillocks.

But it takes more to be a good moderator! **Foremost, it takes time!**

In order to fight off the buggers, inspire the newcomers to become regular participants, hang out in chat to strengthen the community, and to keep the site in the great shape it is in, one has to "sacrifice" a significant amount of time, preferably on a regular basis.

Others have understood that too, and I'm glad that Martin has explicitly stated that he is free and willing to use his time for the community.

**Fact is that I can't.** I simply do not have the time for moderation that this community deserves.

So, thanks again for asking and tickling my vanity, but I have to decline.

However, I'll be happy to fly in to answer some questions and close some crap whenever I can.

Answer (score 17):

I think that in modern society, we tend to categorize things into being "better" than others too often.  Surely being a moderator is more important than being a solid "regular" user? Not really.

It's often a stretched analogy, but moderators are janitors.  We're the folks cleaning up after the football game, which, even though we haven't carried the winning touchdown, we keep the field free from debris and make the stands presentable so the next game can carry on.  However, the game wouldn't exist at all without the athletes, coaches, etc.

We also need athletic directors, people to sell refreshments, announcers, cheerleaders, ticket takers parking lot attendants, etc.  All of these roles are vital to the day-to-day mechanics of the site that keep it flowing and ready for the fans.

The bottom line is, if these two users want to stay on the front lines and fight the good fight, that's more than okay with me! It's really their choice, so I'm happy to let the matter be.

Comment: (substitute "kick the winning goal" if you are a footballer from anywhere else, it still very much fits!)

Comment: "janitors" - no way.  I think of you mods as the highly skilled watchmakers who keep things running smoothly despite the grit and grime.

Comment: @ron: Think not of "janitor" in the perjorative sense but rather as it was intended---the door-keeper.