# Happy (7 + 3 = 10)th Anniversary!

Tags: discussion

## Happy 10th Anniversary!

On the 8th of May 2012 a little site went into public beta. That meant that everyone with access to the Internet could ask questions about their most favourite science: Chemistry.

This little site has steadily grown and evolved with many, many contributing users.

A few years later this community was rewarded not only with high praise, but also with the biggest honour on Stack Exchange:<sup>[*](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/484/4945)</sup>

## Happy 7th Anniversary!

On the 13th of May 2015 Chemistry Stack Exchange graduated. This is now already seven years ago; today actually.

With the graduation came some great perks, the most visible was our very own an special design. We belonged to the "adult club" now.

It gives me (personally) great joy to see how this community evolved and that it is still flourishing. I am looking forward to seeing more great questions being asked and answered.

For now, let's all take a moment and enjoy our accomplishment. Thank you all for being here and making this a unique experience.

It's been quite a journey (if I may say so without sounding overdramatic) but it certainly has been quite… the… journey… .<sup>[**](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2759/4945)</sup>

## Congratulations and Thank You, Everyone!

Comment: Also 3+2+5 ;) https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3762/two-years-later

Comment: yay, i am so happy for that!!! >.<

Comment: Oh blimey. Happy 10th!